# Wireless Router allows VPN routing per host/domain/ip

Tags: wifi, networking, router, ethernet

My current router (ASUS RT-AC658U) I'm quite happy with, however I want to configure it to direct *most* traffic through a VPN. It does support configuring a VPN connection on the router, but in an "all or nothing" manner.  This causes an issue because:

- Gaming over VPN provides a very poor experience
- Netflix (and certain other services) can detect the VPN (most likely identify the IP belongs to a VPN provider) and block their service.

Thus...

I'm looking for a wireless router matching the following:

Supports:

- 2.5 GHz, and 5 GHz
- 802.11ac
- Guest networks
- Port forwarding
- Generally well reviewed, dependable, no major issues, etc.

**More importantly** (and more distinctly from my current router) **it allows VPN traffic with firewall-like rules.**

I am more technically inclined (I'm comfortable with command line, terminal, network troubleshooting), although I don't need a build-it-yourself hard-technical solution if there's an easier out-of-the-box solution.

I'd like to spend

Comment: Spend what? You probably will have a better experience using something like a RPi but it's not out-of-the-box solution, it requires some time.